# Export Google Doc without comments

Tags: google-drive-api, export, comments

I am using the google drive api v3 `files.export` method to get the `text/html` version of a google doc. I noticed that all the currently open comments in the doc also show up in the content as footnotes. I was wondering if there is any way to export the content of the doc without exporting the open comments. I can’t seem to find any options for `files.export` that would disable comments. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, when Google Docs are exported, there are no methods for directly removing comments. So how about this workaround?

1. Retrieve all comment IDs from the Google Doc using `drive.comments.list`.
2. Remove all comments on the Google Doc using `drive.comments.delete`.
3. Export the Google Doc as HTML using `drive.files.export`.

#### Note :

- If you want to continue to use the Google Doc which included comments, at first, please copy the Google Doc.

#### References :

- [drive.comments.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/comments/list)
- [drive.comments.delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/comments/delete)
- [drive.files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

When you will modify HTML using regex, how about a following regex?

```
<sup><a href="#cmnt\w.+?<\/a><\/sup>|<div style=\"border:1px solid black;margin:5px\">[\w\W]+<\/div>
```

- `<sup><a href="#cmnt\w.+?<\/a><\/sup>` is the reference numbers at the upper right.
- `<div style=\"border:1px solid black;margin:5px\">[\w\W]+<\/div>` is the comments at the lower part.

When above regex is used for the exported Google Doc, the result is as follows.

#### From :

[image]

#### To :

[image]

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks @tanaike for your response. I think I am going to try and use some regex to strip out the comments as I do not have write permissions for the drive, but readonly permissions.

Comment: @Suchit Agarwal I'm sorry that I couldn't notice that you don't have the permission as a writer. How about this flow? 1. Download the Google Doc to your Google Drive. By this, you can write it. 2. Retrieve all comment IDs from the Google Doc using drive.comments.list. 3. Remove all comments on the Google Doc using drive.comments.delete. 4. Export the Google Doc as HTML using drive.files.export.

Comment: Thanks @tanaike. Sorry for not being clear. I am doing this on behalf of users in our app, so the logged in user will still need to give us write permissions which is probably a no-go. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Suchit Agarwal No problem. I'm sorry, too. I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 4):

Another workaround would be to duplicate the doc and in the popup screen, DO NOT choose "Copy Comments and Suggestions." Then download the duplicate directly.